# Is my sour dough starter still good if it separates?

Tags: bread

I am starting a sour dough starter.  I am in day six of starting it and it has separated.  Is it still good and should I continue using it?

Comment: By "separated" do you mean a layer of water, beneath which is a later of thicker batter?

Comment: yes, that is what has happened

Answer (score 2):

It's fine.  Just a little extra water.  Pour it off, and then carry on, adding flour and water to the starter and then splitting it.